# How to track each item while doing pagination using sqlalchemy flask?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am writing a get API which will fetch all the user data and return them , Now i am planning to add pagination

GET API:

```
model.py
---------
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username= db.Column(db.String, unique=False, nullable=False)
    city= db.Column(db.String, unique=False, nullable=False)

    def get_user_details(self):
       return temp_dict('username':self.username,'city':self.city)
---------------
api.py
----------------
def get(self):
output_list = []
page_index = request.args.get('index', 1, type=int)
max_item = request.args.get('max', 2, type=int)
list_of_user_obj = User.query.paginate(per_page=max_item, page=page_index)
for each_device_obj in list_of_user_obj.items:
     output_list.append(User.get_user_details(each_device_obj))
 return make_response(jsonify(output_list), status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

This is what i doing . Here i want to track each item like:
if the enduser is asking for page=1 then i should return something like:

```
[
 {
   'user_name':'David',
   'city':"CA"
 },
 {
   'user_name':'Sham',
   'city':"NY"
 }
]
-I want to show in UI table like:
list_id|  username | city
1          David       CA
2          Sham        NY
-Now if the user is asking for page=2 in url then my UI table should like:
list_id|  username | city
3          Jack       WA
4          Klane      NY
-Here point is i dont have list_id in my DB , it should generated based on pagination .
So the question here is , Does SQLALCHEMY cover this type of scenario ? How to do this?
```

Comment: What is missing ? Just the list_id ? What is it for ? Why don't you use the id column from users table ? If it's just an increment, you have many ways to do it

Comment: @Pyglouthon i want to prepare list_id based on user requested for page. let suppose www.somedomain.com/?page=1 then the number of item is coming from response is 2 then list_id will be 1 and 2 , Now if enduser www.somedomain.com/?page=2 then 2 item will come as a response so my list_id will be 3 and 4 not again 1 and 2 .

Comment: So you just have to count. You know the number of item you have per page and the page you are on so page * per_page + index + 1 where index is the current index in your prepare_list loop

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
def get(self):
output_list = []
page_index = request.args.get('index', 1, type=int)
max_item = request.args.get('max', 2, type=int)
init_of_list_id = (page-1)*max_item # Changes Added
list_of_user_obj = User.query.paginate(per_page=max_item, page=page_index)
for each_device_obj in list_of_user_obj.items:
     output_dict =  User.get_user_details(each_device_obj)
     output_dict['list_id'] =  init_of_list_id +1 # Added
     init_of_list_id += 1 # Added
     output_list.append(output_dict)
 return make_response(jsonify(output_list), status.HTTP_200_OK)
```